# Interación entre dos listas en C

Tags: c, estructuras-de-datos, manejo-de-memoria

Estoy tratando de resolver un ejercicio en C. Tengo tres archivos así armados:

Calendario.dat que contiene:

```
año (int)
mes (int)
importe(double)
```

Contribuyentes.csv

```
Id (int)
Titular(string[50])
Codigo postal(int)
```

Pagos.csv

```
Id (int)
año(int)
mes(int)
importe(double)
```

El `file` calendario.dat contiene los importes a pagar que son fijos para cada contribuyente pero cambian cada mes.

Me piden armar un nuevo archivo.dat que contenga la deuda total acumulada por cada contribuyente en todos los años presentes en calendario.dat.
Todos los archivos que tengo no son ordenados de ninguna manera.

Lo que hice fue primero armar una lista donde cada nodo contiene un año y la suma de los importes de cada mes de ese año, sumando los elementos de la lista obtuve el monto total que habria que pagar cada contribuyente a lo largo de todos los años.

Ahora no se bien como calcular cuanto pagó cada contribuyente.. Lo que se me ocurrió fue armar otra lista que contiene el `ID` , el año y un `double` donde voy sumando.

```
fd = fopen("C:/Pagos.csv","r");
if (fd == NULL) {
    puts("ERROR");
    exit(-1);
}
while(!feof(fd)) {
    fscanf(fd,"%d,%d,%d,%lf",&aux2.id,&aux2.anio,&aux2.mes,&aux2.importe);

    if(esta2(lista2,aux2)) {
        sumar2(&lista2,aux2);
    } else agregar2(&lista2,aux2);
}
```

Cuya relativas funciones son:

```
int esta2 (t_nodo2 lista2, t_pagos aux2) {
    if(lista2 == NULL)
        return 0;
    if(lista2->anio == aux2.anio && lista2->id == aux2.id)
        return 1;
    else return esta2(lista2->sig,aux2);
}
```

Agregar 2:

```
void agregar2 (t_nodo2 * lista2, t_pagos aux2) {
    if(*lista2 == NULL) {
        *lista2 = malloc(sizeof(struct s_nodo2));
        (*lista2)->anio = aux2.anio;
        (*lista2)->importe = aux2.importe;
        (*lista2)->id = aux2.id;
        (*lista2)->sig = NULL;
    }
    else agregar2(&(*lista2)->sig,aux2);
}
```

Sumar2:

```
void sumar2 (t_nodo2 * lista2, t_pagos aux2) {
    if((*lista2)->anio == aux2.anio && (*lista2)->id == aux2.id)
        ((*lista2)->importe) += aux2.importe;
    else sumar2(&(*lista2)->sig,aux2);
}
```

Hasta acá todo funciona, el tema es que en la lista tengo el mismo id varias veces por cada año y se me complica bastante teniendo que sumar el monto pagado por cada contribuyente a lo largo de todos los años.

Se me ocurriria armar otra lista que sume por cada ID el monto de cada año y comparar ese total con el total a pagar de cada año que tengo en la primera lista.

Funcionaría, pero me parece que no es la mejor estrategia y me estoy mareando bastante con todas estas listas,

¿Cómo podría encarar el problema de otra manera?

Comment: Las dos que se te ocurren (hacer la suma a fuerza bruta para cada contribuyente/mes) o hacer una segunda con los acumulados son aceptables. Otra es hacer una lista de listas (id -> anio -> meses ) y hacer  la acumulación cuando insertas cada pago. Algo más de detalles en mi respuesta.

Answer (score 0):

Por lo que entiendo, el dato de cuando fue el mes pago no hay que usarlo (y hay que suponer la fecha del pago corresponde al año en que se hizo el pago).

En pseudocodigo yo haría algo así:

```
  for each contribuyente in contribuyentes
     for each anio in anios
         deuda = totalApagar(anio) - pagadoEnAnio(contribuyente.id,anio) 
         agregarDeudaArchivo(contribuyente.id, anio, deuda)
```

donde

`contribuyentes`: lista enlazada de `{ id, titular, cp}` leida de `Contribuyentes.csv` (para este problema no necesitamos todos los datos, pero...)

`anios` : lista enlazada de `{anio [meses] totalanio}`
    donde `meses` es un array de 12 (o 13 si prefieres) elementos (double) (de nuevo, para el problema no se necesita la discriminación por meses, pero...)

`pagos` : lista enlazada de `{ id (pagos1)}`
   donde `(pagos1)` es otra lista de  `{anio,total}` (en este caso no estoy guardando el dato del mes de pago... porque no hace falta me aburrí)

Implementamos una funcion `buscarAnio(anio)` que busca en la lista y
  y otra  `addToAnio(anio,mes,totalmes)` que inserta e inicializa el nuevo año si no existía, agrega el dato del mes al array y acumula en `totalmes`
 Con esto tenemos lo necesario para leer `Calendario.dat`

Implementamos `buscarPagosContrib(id)` `buscarPagosContribAnio(id,anio)`
  `insertarPago(id,anio,importe)`.